# wiredep returns path one directory too deep

Tags: node.js, bower, wiredep

gulpfile is in 'web'
bower_components in 'web'
directory structure:
 web > app > jade > layout.jade (target)
using:

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function () {
  var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

  gulp.src('app/styles/*.scss')
    .pipe(wiredep())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/styles'));

  gulp.src('app/jade/*.jade')
    .pipe(wiredep())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/jade'));
});
```

I get

```
script(src='../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
```

in layout.jade

when I need:

```
script(src='../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
```

Answer (score 3):

all I needed was

```
.pipe(wiredep({
  ignorePath: '../'
}))
```

Comment: Thank you so much I love you!